# How to count string from highlighting in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, count

I wish there is a way to count string with mouse highlighting. For example, if a user highlight a word from a sentence it will count how many string in it and show to the user. Is it possible in tkinter ?

Image:
[image]

Expected output:
it will show how many string is in the word that i highlighted

Comment: in `Text` widget or in `Entry`  widget?

Comment: im using text widgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use `text.selection_get()` to get the text and pass it to `len`.

sample code:

```py
from tkinter import *


def print_count(event):
    if text.tag_ranges('sel'):
        print(len(text.selection_get()))
        print(len(text.selection_get().split())) # gives count of the number of words highlighted
        #print(text.selection_get())


root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.bind('<<Selection>>', print_count)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```